# how to get the keystrokes of a user?

Tags: java, swing, awt, keystroke

I managed to get the user keystrokes and store it in an arrayList of type character. the only problem I have that when the user type something outside the JTextArea I wont be able to get the keystrokes any more. so is there a way of getting the keystrokes even if the user using Microsoft work for instance not the JTextArea.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Sadasd extends JFrame {

    private JTextField userText;
    private JTextArea chatWindow;
     ArrayList<Character> stringList;
    public Sadasd(String host){
        super(" mofo!");
         stringList = new ArrayList<Character>();
        userText = new JTextField();
        userText.setEditable(false);
        userText.addActionListener(
            new ActionListener(){
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
                    userText.setText("");
                }
            }
        );

        add(userText, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        chatWindow = new JTextArea();
        add(new JScrollPane(chatWindow), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(300,150);
        setVisible(true);
    chatWindow.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
       //  System.out.println(e.getKeyChar());
         stringList.add(e.getKeyChar());
        System.out.println(stringList);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }
} );
    }
}
```

Comment: You'll need to use JNA to get key presses outside the app.

Comment: orite thats perfect, can you please guide me how to do it

Comment: Is this homework? JNA is seriously not worth the trouble, just accept the limitation your app can't get keypresses outside your app

Comment: no its not a homework, I am just trying to develop a remote desktop application

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not possible without using any library.

You might want to check [JNativeHook](https://code.google.com/p/jnativehook/) which will do all the hard works for you.

Here an example pasted from the link I gave you :

```
public class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Pressed: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));

        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            GlobalScreen.unregisterNativeHook();
        }
    }

    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Released: " + NativeKeyEvent.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }

    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Key Typed: " + e.getKeyText(e.getKeyCode()));
    }    
}
```

To accomplish this task, `JNativeHook` leverages platform-dependent native code through `Java`'s native interface to create low-level, system-wide hooks and deliver those events to your application.

Comment: The question wants to get keys presses outside the app, i.e. at the OS level..

Comment: @Adam Missed that part at first, edited.

Comment: how can I import the class NativeKeyListener  to the project

Comment: @johan I have the link on my post to the official page. There is a `Download` link at the top.

Comment: i tried to install JNativeHook, but i could not do it

Comment: @johan what problem have you encountered ?

Comment: I am not sure what I have to do in order to use the library in my project, I ve been tring since yesterday but i could not do it

Answer (score 0):

Java does not provide a way to, with standard libraries, fetch keystrokes outside any windows your program owns.

The [Java Native Access](https://github.com/twall/jna) library (and others) provide a way to do this.
If you're searching for a simpler library, you may prefer [JIntellitype](https://code.google.com/p/jintellitype/).